# AEM How to prevent localization happening otb?

Tags: internationalization, aem

I have a scenario wherein i18n becomes overhead to content authors. The authors want dialog labels to be in English only for all locales. But certain headings/labels on dialog gets localized as they are available in otb dictionaries. Example label 'Advanced' from page properties dialog gets translated for non-english sites.

Is there a way I can prevent internalization happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to AEM's documentation for [i18n](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components/i18n/i18n-dev.html), you can see its driven by the locale/language set in `slingRequest`. you can override this by explicitly fixing the i18n but if **you do that none of your translations will work** -

```
Locale pageLang = new Locale("en");
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = slingRequest.getResourceBundle(pageLang);
I18n i18n = new I18n(resourceBundle);
```

An other alternative (a little extra effort) in you need to do this only for dialog boxes is -

- Create your own dictionary for translations, refer [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components/i18n/translator.html#par_title_0)
- Use unique name-spacing for your keys eg - myapp.mycomponent_abc.label
- Use above keys in your component dialog to ensure that your version of translation is picked. If for all languages you want english only dialogs, all your have to do is duplicate your english dictionary and change the language key in it to relevant language while keeping translations still in english.

Comment: second option is what i have done. this localization is for cq widgets happening otb. Hence cant override otb calls to set default language. But i created custom dictionaries which works.